# How to access nested data JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase, react-native

I need to access the username of a user stored in the Firebase Realtime Database, in a UsersList.

[image: Realtime Database]

How do I access that?

Code:

[image: Header.tsx]
[image: Console output]

I tried all the stuff shown above, but would get result data: undefined.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Use the [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) tools available to insert it into your question. This improves the ability to index it for search and speeds up the time it takes to respond to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use foreach

```
const readUserData = () => {
  firebase.database().ref('UsersList/').once('value', function (snapshot) {

      let values = [];
      console.log('child.key',child.key);
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        values.push(child.val());
      });
      console.log(values);
    
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  )}
}
```

Comment: And then I get [{"email": "dguri...", "username": "David Guri"}] How do I access the username part?

Comment: values.username